# Creating border around specific areas of images

Tags: deep-learning, image-segmentation

I have some 1000+ image, containing data like this
[image]

Red area: Symbols
Grey area: Text describing the symbol
Note: I draw these red/grey boxes just for visualization only.

Each symbol is unique in this 1000+ images. I want to draw borders around those locations. Which algorithm/technique I need to use so that it can draw border around those places correctly. As these are unique symbols the only valid guess is these are starting from left side then some space then the text.

Comment: such segmentation technique is called Image Captioning; search in that direction